# performance of boost multi_index_container

Tags: c++, performance, boost-multi-index

I am interested to know the performance of multi_index_container for the following use case:

```
struct idx_1 {};
struct idx_2 {};

typedef multi_index_container<
    Object,
    indexed_by<
      // Keyed by: idx1
      hashed_unique<
        tag<idx_1>,
        unique_key >,
      // Keyed by: (attribute1, attribute2 and attribute3)
      ordered_non_unique<
        tag<idx_2>,
        composite_key<
          Object,
          attribute1,
          attribute2,
          attribute3 > >
    >
  > ObjectMap;
```

I need a map to save the object, and the number of objects should be more than 300,000. while each object has 1 unique key and 3 attributes. The details of the keys:

1. unique key is "unique" as the name
2. each attribute only has a few possible values, say there's only 16 combinations. So with 300,000 objects, each combination will have a list of 300,000/16 objects
3. attribute1 needs to be modified from one value to another value occasionally
4. object finding is always be done via the unique_key while the composite_key is used to iterating objects with one or several attributes

For such use case, multi_index_container is a very good fit as I don't need to maintain several map independently. For the unique key part, I believe hashed_unique is a good candidate instead of ordered_unique.

But I am extremely not comfortable about the "ordered_non_unique" part. I don't know how's implemented in boost. My guess it boost maintain a list of objects in a single list for each combination similar to the unordered_map(forgive me if it's too naive!). If that's the case, modify the attribute an existing object will be a big pain as it requires to 1) go through a long list of objects for a particular combination 2) execute the equal comparison 3) and move the destination combination.

the steps that I suspect with high latency:

```
ObjectMap objects_;
auto& by_idx1 = objects_.get<idx1>();
auto it = by_idx1.find(some_unique_key);
Object new_value;
by_idx1.modify(it, [&](const Object& object) {
  object = new_value;
});
```

My concern is that whether the last "modify" function has some liner behavior as stated to go through some potential long list of objects under one combination...

Comment: "modify the attribute an existing object will be a big pain as it requires to 1) go through a long list of objects for a particular combination 2) execute the equal comparison 3) and move the destination combination." - you should describe this more thoroughly... when you want to make the modification, are you saying you will know the attribute[1-3] values but not the unique key, but as you iterate the matches you'll somehow recognise a single value to be modified by comparing some other field(s)?  If you want that more efficient, clearly you need an extra index on *that/those* field(s).

Comment: @TonyD, I use the unique_key to find the object and call the "modify" function of multi_index_container to updates the attributes. I believe the container will automatically re-arrange the layout based on the updated attributes. I am worrying about this "re-arrangement" operation. Edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: I think you should just implement it and then measure to see if there's a performance problem... I'd be very surprised.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a very specific piece of code, I'd suggest you benchmark and profile it using a large amount of real-world data.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabio comments, your best option is to profile the case and see the outcome. Anyway, an `ordered_non_unique` index is implemented exactly as a `std::multimap`, namely via a regular rb-tree with the provision that elements with equivalent keys are allowed to coexist in the container; no lists of equivalent elements or anything. As for `modify` (for your particular use case `replace` is a better fit), the following procedure is executed:

- Check if the element is in place: O(1).
- If not, rearrange: O(log n), which for 300,000 elements amounts to a maximum of 19 element comparisons (not 300,000/16=18,750 as you suggest): these comparisons are done lexicographically on the triple (`attribute1`, `attribute2`, `attribute3`). Is this fast enough or not? Well, that depends on your performance requirements, so only profiling can really tell.

Comment: I don't get the part that average of 300,000/16 elements with the same key, how internally it's saved in either multimap or the ordered_non_unique, because the container cannot save them in a tree like structure since it doesn't know whether the element should go to the left child tree or right child tree since they have the same key value.

Comment: The algorithms for rb-tree insertion work the same way with unique and non-unique elements; the only added characteristic in the case of equivalent elements is that they end up inserted in such a way that linear traversal of the structure meets all equivalent elements together. For instance if you insert (1,2,4,2,3,5,2,4) the resulting traversal is 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5.